# Signed by authority java applet prompts but not run?

Tags: java, windows, applet

I created an applet for printing. It is signed by authority (not self-signed). Before signing I added to MANIFEST these lines:

```
    Permissions: all-permissions 
    Codebase: *
```

In Linux systems (Ubuntu, Mint x86 and x64) it works fine. But when I tried to run it on Windows XP and Windows 7 I also get the prompt and click "Run" button, but it does not start.

[image]

When I change to Medium the security level of Java it starts, but by default the security level is High. Where is the problem?

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including these two lines (and once again signing) it works fine:

```
    Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: * 
    Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Initial two lines (Codebase and Permissions) are kept.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know with the last release of Java 7 the "Do you want to run this application?" window is always displayed.

There is also always a window if your applet doesn't require extra privileges with a less warning message.

I wouldn't advice you to keep * as codebase.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#codebase

"An asterisk (*) can be used as a wildcard only at the beginning of the domain name"